# Can a directive inherit a controller AND an isolate scope?

Tags: angularjs

My app has one main controller, "AppCtrl as ac", which contains lots of helpful utility functions and as well as information I want to be easily accessible, such as the logged in user's userID.  Currently ac is accessible from all views and so everything is great.

I'm trying to fiddle around with directives now, however, and I'm running into trouble.  I'm making a simple directive which needs access to the functions/data in ac.  At the same time, however, it looks like I need to use an isolate scope, since I plan on using the directive multiple times in a view, being passed slightly different info.  I don't want to give it a new controller, as I'd like to access the data that the main AppCtrl has.

Any advice as to how I'd accomplish this?  I'm new to angular and the MVC paradigm, so let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your code so that we can see what type of directive you are trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can pass values around and into isolate scopes in angular, although not one of them is comfortable to use.

### Standard solution: "parameterize" your isolate scope

In the JS:

```
myModule
    .controller('AppController', function AppController() {
        this.myFunction = function myFunction() {
            console.log('Hello from myFunction!');
            return 2;
        };
        this.myData = 40;
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function () {

        return {
            // isolate scope!
            scope: {
                restrict: 'E',
                twoWayData: '=data',
                evaluateExpression: '&expression'
            },
            template: '<span>{{ twoWayData + evaluateExpression() }}</span>'
            // no controller! no link function! no nothing
        };

    });
```

In the markup:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as ac">
    <my-directive data="ac.myData" expression="ac.myFunction()">
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

And if I'm not mistaken, your questions should be answered.

### Dumdum solution: `$scope.$parent`

Even though your scope is isolate(d), it still has access to the outer scope (you can't talk about "parent scope" anymore) using `$scope.$parent`. A true child scope simply inherits prototypally (prototypically??) from the parent scope in addition to keeping a reference to it with the `$parent` property. An isolate scope only has the `$parent` property.

Just don't use this "solution". It breaks encapsulation, you don't know how far up the chain you will have to go (how many parents of parents do you need to find to get to the properties you need?) and it shows poor design. The only use I can think of for it is when you can establish some kind of contract that your directive should only be used in contexts where it can count on `$scope.$parent` having certain properties, as in

```
var p = $scope.$parent;
if (!(typeof p.foo === 'function' && typeof p.data === 'object')) {
    throw new Error('Illegal!');
}
// Otherwise go on with business
```

But even that really should be your last resort. I've worked with angular quite a lot and I've never needed a directive to check on its outer scope like this.

### Dumdum solution in disguise: services

You can count on a child directive's controller being instantiated later than a controller further up the scope chain, and inversely for link functions (angular traverses the DOM and instantiates controllers pre-order and runs link functions post-order). Therefore, if you feed data into a service in `AppController`, you can count on it being present for `myDirective`:

```
myModule
    .factory('MyService', function myServiceFactory() {
        return {
            a: null,
            b: null
        };
    })
    .controller('AppController', [ 'MyService', function AppController(MyService) {
        MyService.a = 'foo';
        MyService.b = 'bar';
    }])
    .directive('myDirective', function () {

        return {
            scope: {
                restrict: 'E'
            },
            controller: ['MyService', function MyDirectiveController($scope, MyService) {
                $scope.a = MyService.a;
                $scope.b = MyService.b;
            }],
            template: '<span>{{ a + b }}</span>'
        };

    });
```

This looks plain dumb. But this is actually what some people do when the data is created at a certain point in the scope tree and is needed 9 scopes and 3 layers of isolation down the chain.

Let's face it: a service is a global, it doesn't matter what you call it. This only makes sense from an engineering standpoint if you regard a service as some kind of context that you establish at some point in the tree and do not use wildly out of context.

### Other solutions

You can use `require` in your directive definition object. It's even less powerful than using `$scope.$parent` because your directive is not agnostic with respect to the controller associated to the outer scope.

You can stop being anal about giving ALL THE DIRECTIVES AN ISOLATE SCOPE!!! and instead use `scope: true` and `scope: false` judiciously.

If you use ui-router, you can even use states to define "contexts" within which state controllers will be injected with resolved data, or you can get the data from the `$state` service (and its `data` property) which is slightly better than getting it from a random service created to serve as a global.

Answer (score 0):

Place all your important functions into angular services and your logged in user info into $rootScope.

Then inject services and $rootScope into controller for your directive.

If you are really lazy you can place everything into $rootScope and not bother with services but I do not advise you to do so.

Comment: So it's expected that every directive which ever needs to call functions should have its own unique, freshly-instantiated controller? All its functions would just be wrappers for functions of various services; seems like a lot of overhead and boilerplate.

Comment: @user1636815 A directive should have a controller (or link), but you only need to define it once; that's one reason why they're useful. If you don't think it's worth having a controller/link for something, do you think it's worth having a directive for it at all?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

In javascript

```
 (function(){

    angular
    .module('exampleApp', []);

    angular
     .module('exampleApp')
     .controller('ExampleController', Controller);

    function Controller(){
        var vm = this;

        vm.coolMethod = coolFn;
        vm.anotherMethod = anotherFn;
        vm.variableToDirective = "value";

        function coolFn(){
            alert('function cool');
        }

        function anotherFn(){
            alert('another function');
        }
    }

    angular
     .module('exampleApp')
     .directive('myDirective', directive);

    function directive(){
        var ddo = {
            restrict: 'E',
            bindToController: true,
            controller: 'ExampleController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            link: linkFn,
            scope: {
                myValue: '@'
            },
            template: '<h1 ng-bind="vm.myValue"></h1><div class="directive-class"><button ng-click="vm.coolMethod()">It is Cool eh?</button><button ng-click="vm.anotherMethod()">Another</button></div>'
        }

        return ddo;

        function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
            console.log(scope.vm);
        }
    }


  })();
```

In HTML

```
<div ng-app="exampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController as example">
        <input ng-model="example.variableToDirective" />
        <my-directive my-value="10"></my-directive>
        <my-directive my-value="20"></my-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working codepen: http://goo.gl/B1WGtb